# Elasticsearch - Use wildcard in Multi Get Java API

Tags: elasticsearch

In Elasticsearch, is there a way to use wildcard to get document from multiple indices in Java API ? For example, currently I have to use prepareMultiGet as below:

```
MultiGetResponse multiGetItemResponses = client.prepareMultiGet()
.add("index_01", "index_01", "foo")
.add("index_02", "index_02", "foo")
.add("index_03", "index_03", "foo")
.get();
```

May I just use a wildcard index name, for example index_* to get doc from the indices ?

Comment: Although I don't write with Java but with C#, but it is possible in NEST (elastic API for C#) so I'm pretty sure it is possible in java. In the end, all this API does is to transform your queries  into a json which apply to Elastic Rest API

Answer (score 0):

All CRUD APIs on Document level are single-index APIs. So it looks like I can't use wildcard for index name.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/java-docs.html